# Calling two NSURLSessionTask completion blocks one after another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I have the following setup that uses AFNetworking to make calls to my server. I have used an example I found on the internet to include a completion block so I know when the call has finished.

**File "FCEngine.m"**

```
- (void)fetchBusinessProfile:(NSString *)userID userAccessToken:(NSString *)userAccessToken completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *json, BOOL success))completion {

/// Validate the user token again the user id.

NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:userAccessToken,@"user_access_token",
                            userID,@"user_id",
                            nil];


AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = serializer;

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

[manager POST:@"" parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON Business Profile: %@", responseObject);

    fetchBusinessProfileCompletion(responseObject, YES);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

    //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    NSMutableDictionary *errorResponse = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [errorResponse setObject:@"connection_error" forKey:@"state"];
    [errorResponse setObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"description"];

    fetchBusinessProfileCompletion(errorResponse, YES);

}];

}

- (void)fetchNotifications:(NSString *)userID userAccessToken:(NSString *)userAccessToken completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *json, BOOL success))completion {

/// Validate the user token again the user id.

NSDictionary *parameters = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:userAccessToken,@"user_access_token",
                            userID,@"user_id",
                            nil];


AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = serializer;

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

[manager POST:@"" parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

    //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    completion(responseObject, YES);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

    //NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    NSMutableDictionary *errorResponse = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [errorResponse setObject:@"connection_error" forKey:@"state"];
    [errorResponse setObject:[error localizedDescription] forKey:@"description"];

    completion(errorResponse, YES);

}];


}
```

The following is how I make the call on **Main View Controller**

```
- (void)MyMethods {

 [self.fcEngine fetchBusinessProfile:userID userAccessToken:userAccessToken completion:^(NSDictionary *json, BOOL success) {

    /// Response here


}];

[self.fcEngine fetchNotifications:self.userID userAccessToken:self.userAccessToken completion:^(NSDictionary *json, BOOL success) {

       //// Response here

 }];

}
```

Now the problem is that the 2 calls are made one after another and when I fetch the data for one e.g. "fetchBusinessProfile" the competition block on both is called.

Have I set this up wrong? If 2 or more calls I only want the completion to be called for that particular block and not them all.

Comment: I don't understand.  You'd like to call one after the other?  Pass a completion block to the first one that calls the second.

Comment: No I call fetch profile first and then fetch notifications almost straight away after. Now I think Im calling fetch notifications before fetch profile has finished so when fetch profile finishes it calls both completion blocks.

Comment: yes, if you don't nest call #2 in completion block of call #1, they will execute more or less in parallel and both completions will be called.  if they must be called in sequence, you must call #2 in block for #1.

Comment: maybe you want to call them concurrently but have only one block called when they are both done?  that's possible too, a little trickier

Comment: Updated the above code to make more sense. Is there any way to do this without having to nestle? What about if I init FCEngine twice instead of self?

Comment: if you want two things to happen sequentially, you must know when the first one is done in order to begin the second.  that is exactly what's known within the first completion block, therefore (using blocks, anyway) nesting is required.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand asynchronous as well as completion blocks. If you make the 2 network calls as defined above, they can happen in any order. The `completion` in `fetchBusinessProfile` and `fetchNotifications` will be **different** completion blocks ... **unless** you make them the same.

For example:

```
 [self.fcEngine fetchBusinessProfile:userID userAccessToken:userAccessToken completion:^(NSDictionary *json, BOOL success) {

    /// Handle response
    // Note calling the SAME completion block
    sameCompletionBlockAlreadyDefined();


}];

[self.fcEngine fetchNotifications:self.userID userAccessToken:self.userAccessToken completion:^(NSDictionary *json, BOOL success) {

    //// Handle response
    // Note calling the SAME completion block
    sameCompletionBlockAlreadyDefined();

 }];
```

In this case, `sameCompletionBlockAlreadyDefined()` is some already defined block. In this case, the body of the block of each call is indeed, but funnel to the same call via `sameCompletionBlockAlreadyDefined`. It is possible you are confused because `completion` happens to be named the same in your first snippet.

Note your question is really poorly phrased so it isn't fully clear on what you mean.

The larger question is what is your goal? Do you want only one completion block to be called at the end? Or you want fully distinct completion blocks? Both require different techniques. Be clear on what your goal is.

The former would be best service with a `dispatch_group`. The latter requires different completion blocks.

An example of dispatch group would be something like:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);

[self.fcEngine fetchBusinessProfile:userID userAccessToken:userAccessToken completion:^(NSDictionary *json, BOOL success) {

    /// Handle response
    dispatch_group_leave(group);


];

self.fcEngine fetchNotifications:self.userID userAccessToken:self.userAccessToken completion:^(NSDictionary *json, BOOL success) {

    //// Handle response
    dispatch_group_leave(group);

}];

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

// This would be some completion block which means all is done
completion();
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the issue as you have. I guess Im simply trying to make 2 AFNetworking calls but I don't need one to finish before I call the other.

Comment: What you are already doing is making the calls be independent. I think you are getting confused because the name `completion` in both methods in your first snippet. If you put in `NSLog` printing diff statements, you will see they are called independently. Remember they can happen out of order. As mentioned, if part of your handling the response call another common block or method, it may look like what you are describing is your problem.

Comment: Ok I've done a bit of testing and it seems that call 1 is performed first fine and then when I NSLOG the results of call 2 it seems to be a copy of call 1.  Out of interest would it have anything to do with "NSURLSessionTask"?

Comment: You need to post your actual code where you call AFNetworking. It would also be good if you just isolated things to the bare minimum to make sure you are not introducing weird side effects in your code

Comment: Just updated the code to show the call to AFNetworking. Thanks for the help all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to be slightly critical here. You state "seems to be", but looking at your code, I don't think you're thorough in determining this. Add unique `NSLog` before the `POST` and in the `success` and `failure` blocks. Really, you should use a debugger to walk through the code. Set the breakpoints before the `POST` and in the `success` and `failure` blocks for each. Typically when having problems like you are having is because there is a lack of discipline in covering all the angles. Yes I know you've been spending time. Time spent is not the same as being thorough.

Comment: Done all the debugging and used the debugger to step through the code, tried NSLog numerous time and also checked all the server code.

Comment: I assume in the `POST` `@""` is the valid URL, correct. Print out what `NSURLSessionTask`'s `currentRequest` is and see what the URL is. I use AFNetworking and have done similar code. It does it properly. There is either something more subtle here or you are misinterpreting results. I run multiple concurrent requests. Server code should have nothing to do with this. This is client code.

Comment: BTW, since you really are not concretely answering the results from recommendations (which makes it hard to help) you have stepped through the code and verified that both `fetchBusinessProfile` and `fetchNotifications` call their own `POST` and that each one each results in `success` or `failure`?

Comment: Unbelievable after all the changes it turns out the code above was fine and it was an issue with the PHP server code. It turns out the PHP was returning a different set of results as JSON which happen to be the same as the results for the first call. Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Just be aware those are 2 different things. The same response payload versus the same completion block being called represent 2 very diff things. Anyways, glad you got it working.